# invalid class name: execution has been thrown by target of an invocation in Unity 5 : Integrating Google Play Services

Tags: google-play-services, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I'm trying to integrate Google Play Services and getting the following error

> invalid class name: execution has been thrown by target of an invocation

I updated "Google Play Services", "Google Repository", Android Support Repository and JDK but it didn't help.

I am using unity 5.4.2, JDK 1.8.0 131, Google play services 0.9.37

[image: invalid class name]

Comment: What's the exact version of Unity, JDK, Google Play Services, etc.

Comment: unity 5.4.2 , JDK 1.8.0 131 , GPS 0.9.37

Comment: Please update your question with those details.

Comment: Try the following solution in this [Unity thread](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/google-mobile-ad-plugin-google-play-services-solved.372607/). Don't know if this helps but try this [Google Service Unity Plugin](https://github.com/unity-plugins/google-services-unity) plugin as well.

Comment: There was a bug in the jar resolver which is included in the plugin.  Try updating the plugin to 0.9.38a or play-services-jarresolver 1.2.19 or higher.

Comment: thanks @ClaytonWilkinson.. Solved

Answer (score 0):

Update the Android Sdk: 
Extras ->

- Android Support Repository
- Google Play service
- Google Repository

[image]

Use GooglePlayGamesPlugin-0.9.39a